# Updating Userform 2 from Userform 1?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have Userforms 1 and 2. I would like to do something on userform2 from userform1 but the problem is userform2 opens but does nothing. If i put the code on userform2 module then it works but i want to do everything from userform1 and just update some results on userform2 while userform1 doing somthing. Any idea?.

code on userform1

```
Userform2.show
Userform2.textbox1.value="hi"
```

above code does not display "hi" in textbox1 of userform2.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the properties of both userforms to ShowModal = False

This will allow them to interact.

you could do this on show:

```
UserForm1.Show (False)
```